# sudo port install opencv を実行してもgmp build がいつも失敗する。

Tags: macos, opencv

```
Error: Failed to build gmp: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
Error: Processing of port opencv failed
```

現状ここから進めません。具体的な解決方法もしくは確認に足りない内容があれば教えてください。
- OS:macOS Sierra 10.12.6
- xcode:Ver.9.2(9C40b)

追記
/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/main.log　
の内容

```
version:1
:debug:sysinfo macOS 10.12 (darwin/16.7.0) arch i386
:debug:sysinfo MacPorts 2.5.4
:debug:sysinfo Xcode 9.2
:debug:sysinfo SDK 10.12
:debug:sysinfo MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: 10.12
:debug:main dropping privileges: euid changed to 503, egid changed to 501.
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (gmp)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.archivefetch (gmp)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (gmp)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (gmp)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.extract (gmp)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.patch (gmp)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.configure (gmp)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:build build phase started at Tue May 21 13:36:28 JST 2019
:notice:build --->  Building gmp
:debug:build Executing org.macports.build (gmp)
:debug:build Environment: 
:debug:build CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES'
:debug:build CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS'
:debug:build CPATH='/opt/local/include'
:debug:build LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib'
:debug:build MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.12'
:info:build Executing:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all 
:debug:build system:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all 
:info:build make: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2'
:info:build /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
:info:build make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2'
:info:build Making all in tests
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests'
:info:build Making all in .
:info:build make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests'
:info:build make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
:info:build make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests'
:info:build Making all in devel
:info:build make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/devel'
:info:build make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
:info:build make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/devel'
:info:build Making all in mpn
:info:build make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/mpn'
:info:build make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
:info:build make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macp
orts.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/mpn'
:info:build Making all in mpz
:info:build make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/mpz'
:info:build make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
:info:build make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/mpz'
:info:build Making all in mpq
:info:build make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/mpq'
:info:build make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
:info:build make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/mpq'
:info:build Making all in mpf
:info:build make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/mpf'
:info:build make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
:info:build make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/mpf'
:info:build Making all in rand
:info:build make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/rand'
:info:build make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
:info:build make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/rand'
:info:build Making all in misc
:info:build make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/misc'
:info:build make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
:info:build make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/misc'
:info:build Making all in cxx
:info:build make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/cxx'
:info:build make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
:info:build make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests/cxx'
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/tests'
:info:build Making all in mpn
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/mpn'
:info:build /bin/sh ../libtool --mode=compile --tag=CC ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4="m4" /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_`echo addmul_1 | sed 's/_$//'` -I/opt/local/include  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell  `test -f 'addmul_1.asm' || echo './'`addmul_1.asm
:info:build /bin/sh ../libtool --mode=compile --tag=CC ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4="m4" /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_`echo mode1o | sed 's/_$//'` -I/opt/local/include  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell  `test -f 'mode1o.asm' || echo './'`mode1o.asm
:info:build /bin/sh ../libtool --mode=compile --tag=CC ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4="m4" /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  
-D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_`echo mod_1_1 | sed 's/_$//'` -I/opt/local/include  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell  `test -f 'mod_1_1.asm' || echo './'`mod_1_1.asm
:info:build /bin/sh ../libtool --mode=compile --tag=CC ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4="m4" /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_`echo mod_1_2 | sed 's/_$//'` -I/opt/local/include  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell  `test -f 'mod_1_2.asm' || echo './'`mod_1_2.asm
:info:build libtool: compile:  ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4=m4 /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_addmul_1 -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell addmul_1.asm  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/addmul_1.o
:info:build libtool: compile:  ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4=m4 /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_mod_1_2 -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell mod_1_2.asm  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/mod_1_2.o
:info:build libtool: compile:  ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4=m4 /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_mode1o -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell mode1o.asm  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/mode1o.o
:info:build libtool: compile:  ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4=m4 /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_mod_1_1 -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell mod_1_1.asm  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/mod_1_1.o
:info:build m4  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -DOPERATION_addmul_1 -DPIC addmul_1.asm >tmp-addmul_1.s
:info:build m4  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -DOPERATION_mod_1_2 -DPIC mod_1_2.asm >tmp-mod_1_2.s
:info:build m4  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -DOPERATION_mode1o -DPIC mode1o.asm >tmp-mode1o.s
:info:build m4  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -DOPERATION_mod_1_1 -DPIC mod_1_1.asm >tmp-mod_1_1.s
:info:build  /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_mode1o -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell tmp-mode1o.s -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/mode1o.o
:info:build  /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_mod_1_2 -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell tmp-mod_1_2.s -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/mod_1_2.o
:info:build  /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_mod_1_1 -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell tmp-mod_1_1.s -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/mod_1_1.o
:info:build  /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_addmul_1 -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell tmp-addmul_1.s -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/addmul_1.o
:info:build libtool: compile:  ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4=m4 /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_mod_1_2 -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell mod_1_2.asm -o mod_1_2.o >/dev/null 2>&1
:info:build libtool: compile:  ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4=m4 /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_mode1o -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell mode1o.asm -o mode1o.o >/dev/null 2>&1
:info:build libtool: compile:  ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4=m4 /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_mod_1_1 -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell mod_1_1.asm -o mod_1_1.o >/dev/null 2>&1
:info:build libtool: compile:  ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4=m4 /usr/bin/clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_addmul_1 -I/opt/local/include -O2 -pedantic -
fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell addmul_1.asm -o addmul_1.o >/dev/null 2>&1
:info:build make[2]: *** [addmul_1.lo] Error 1
:info:build make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
:info:build make[2]: *** [mode1o.lo] Error 1
:info:build make[2]: *** [mod_1_2.lo] Error 1
:info:build make[2]: *** [mod_1_1.lo] Error 1
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2/mpn'
:info:build make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
:info:build make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2'
:info:build make: *** [all] Error 2
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2'
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/work/gmp-6.1.2" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all 
:info:build Exit code: 2
:error:build Failed to build gmp: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 25790 2
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
:debug:build     while executing
:debug:build "system {*}$notty {*}$nice $fullcmdstring"
:debug:build     invoked from within
:debug:build "command_exec build"
:debug:build     (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
:debug:build     invoked from within
:debug:build "$procedure $targetname"
:error:build See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/main.log for details.
```

Comment: `/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gmp/gmp/main.log` の内容を追記してください。

Comment: お待たせしました。変更しました。